# Backbone.js .destroy Passing Additional Params?

Tags: backbone.js

When .destroy'ing a Model, I need to pass an additional parameter to my Rails app.  I've read a few posts on how to do this, however my Rails app still isn't recognizing it.  Any suggestions?  The parameter is `program_id`

```
var thisDeal = new WhiteDeals.Models.EditorDeal({ id: dealID }); 
thisDeal.destroy({headers: { program_id: dealProgram.id } })
```

Here's the server log.  As you can see, the program_id parameter isn't showing up:

```
Started DELETE "/editor_deals/46" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-13 13:26:32 -0700
Processing by DashboardController#deal_destroy as JSON
Parameters: {"id"=>"46"}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `thisDeal.destroy({data: { program_id: dealProgram.id } })`?

Comment: It works!  I thought I had tried that before, but I guess I hadn't.  If you want to add this as an answer, I'll check it.  Just include processData: true also, since it does not work without that turned to true.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The object what you pass as a parameter to `destroy` will eventually end up as the settings parameter to a [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call.

So if you need to send additional data you need to use the `data` proeprty:

```
var thisDeal = new WhiteDeals.Models.EditorDeal({ id: dealID }); 
thisDeal.destroy({data: { program_id: dealProgram.id }, processData: true})
```